# How to exploit a misconfigured CORS policy when a per user authorization token is required?

Tags: api, cors

We recently got an API for security audit. The CORS headers of the API seems mis-configured as when we tried requesting the endpoint with `http://attacker.com` as origin the server returned the following in the response headers:

```
access-control-allow-credentials: true    
access-control-allow-methods: GET, POST, DELETE, PUT    
access-control-allow-origin: http://attacker.com
```

Though the site is vulnerable, but the problem which is blocking us from creating an exploit impact is that the site send an authorization token in each request, which is unique for each user. Any ideas on how to go ahead in a situation like this?

Comment: Where in the request would teh authorization token be? In a cookie? In a header? If so, what header?

Comment: Its in the headers, named Authorization: Bearer

Answer (score 3):

Cross origin requests are dangerous because it makes it possible to use the session of the user to make requests as that user. This works because a cookie is sent along with the request and implicitly authenticates the user to the web application under attack.

If your application does not use cookies but instead uses a header to keep the session token in, the danger of cross origin requests is mitigated. You can still do requests to the server, but not under the session of the user.

Comment: Requests without the auth bearer are all requests that doesn't leak anything in response, nor that does perform any sensitive action, so there's no point in performing them

Comment: But this attack can only be done if XSS is done on your website right?

Comment: @majidarif If there is XSS, the attacker can presumably read the auth token from Web storage and perform any action that require it.